# Download servlet is very slow

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have written a servlet which will download the file from a server location. In our own INTRAnet the download seems to be very very slow and also when I have the Adobe addon installed in my browser and if I am downloading a PDF file, the Adobe addon will display the progress bar while downloading the PDF but this is not happening in my case! Below is my code! Should I not response it as attachment?

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "inline; filename=\"" + fileNameWithExtension
        + "\"");
FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(
        filePathWithExtension);
BufferedInputStream bufferInStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                fileInStream);
int cnt;
while ((cnt = bufferInStream.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(cnt);
}
fileInStream.close();
out.close();
```

Not sure if there is a better way to do. Basically I tried converting one of my dot net code into this Java Servlet. THe current .NET code is very fast compared to this!

This is hosted on Apache Tomcat and the .NET code is hosted on IIS.

Comment: To show the progressbar you have to set the size of the document you are retrieving in the response header (look into the response class for examples).
The speed is somewhat dependent on how many bytes you retrieve in every read/write action.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Thanks! Yeah I have found something about size now and trying to use it. And the speed is there be any variable I need to set for the bytes? Somewhere in tomcat?

Comment: For speed, the method of Thomas (below) will work (as he said: Debug might be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing a byte at a time is horrifically inefficient. The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more if you like
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

And you should not use a `Writer` here, use an `OutputStream.`

Comment: When I tried reading with offset I am getting error - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`